# How to stick div at bottom of page when it has completely entered the viewport?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

What I try to achieve is the following:

I have a div anywhere on my page. I would like to fix this div at the bottom of the page when it has completely entered the viewport.

What I have tried so far:

```
// section.js

(function ($) {
    'use strict';

     $(function () {
         var sections = $('.js-section');

         sections.each(function () {
             var section = $(this);
             var sticky = section.hasClass('js-section-sticky');

             if (sticky) {
                 $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
                     var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                     var sectionTop = section.offset().top - section.height() - windowTop;

                     if (windowTop > sectionTop) {
                         section.addClass('section--fixed-bottom');
                     }
                     else {
                        section.removeClass('section--fixed-bottom');
                     }
                 });
              }
         });
     });
})(window.jQuery);
```

However, currently the section appears too early. It appears immediately and not when it has completely entered the viewport. Additionally, if I scroll up it disappears too late.

Comment: shouldn't section top just be `section.offset().top + section.height()`?

Comment: @Pete you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your code with my below code

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

     $(function () {
         var sections = $('.js-section');

         sections.each(function () {
             var section = $(this);
             var sticky = section.hasClass('js-section-sticky');
             var sectionTop = section.offset().top + section.height();
             if (sticky) {
                 $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
                     var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height();

                     if (windowTop > sectionTop) {
                         section.addClass('section--fixed-bottom');
                         section.next().css("margin-top", section.next().css("margin-top").replace("px", "") + section.height());
                     }
                     else {
                        section.removeClass('section--fixed-bottom');
                        var marginTop = section.next().css("margin-top").replace("px", "") - section.height();
                        if(marginTop < 0) 
                           marginTop*(-1);
                        section.next().css("margin-top", marginTop);
                     }
                 });
              }
         });
     });
})(window.jQuery);
```

It will work fine

Comment: thank you for the try but it does not work as expected it keeps jumping plus other sections are moving too

Comment: that space has to be filled by the next coming elements as the section changes its position type to fixed or else the area would look blank and that doesnt look good either